# queens over cloud instillation fails because keepalived container restarting always

Tags: openstack, openstack-nova, keepalived, tripleo

We are deploying Openstack queens (3 controller and 4 compute HCI ) ,but its failing with Can't connect to MySQL server on '172.16.12.9' ([Errno 113] No route to host) . 172.16.12.9 is my api server IP and this is manged by keepalived/haproxy . But When I checked the keeplaived container its always restarting hence its not able to assign the 172.16.12.9 floating IP to any instance.

> [root@overcloud-controller-0 ~]# docker ps |grep keep  32837abc03ad
>   192.168.24.1:4000/tripleoqueens/centos-binary-keepalived:current-tripleo "dumb-init --singl..." 2 hours ago  Restarting (0) 58 minutes ago 
>   keepalived

Could you please help me why this keep alived is always restarting ? docker log is attached

> Script security disabled  Default script uid:gid 0:0
>   ------< SSL definitions >------  Using autogen SSL context Keepalived_vrrp exited with permanent error CONFIG. Terminating
>   Stopping Stopped Unexpected argument(s): | tee /var/log/keepalived.log
>   Stopped Keepalived v1.3.5 (03/19,2017), git commit v1.3.5-6-g6fa32f2
>   Unexpected argument(s): | tee /var/log/keepalived.log

answer file :

```
templates: /usr/share/openstack-tripleo-heat-templates/
environments:
- environments/network-isolation.yaml
- environments/net-single-nic-with-vlans.yaml
- environments/network-environment.yaml
- environments/ips-from-pool-all.yaml
- environments/scheduler-hints.yaml
- environments/ceph-ansible/ceph-ansible.yaml
- environments/storage-config.yaml
- environments/node-info.yaml
- environments/overcloud_images.yaml
```

Is there somthing I need to give specific to keepalived ?

Comment: Solved the issue my self .Keepalived puppet was not able to identify the the interface name hence ,service was restarting continuously

Comment: This is not a programming question, it is much better suited on ServerFault site.